# Javascript prototype extension weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, foreach, split, prototype

Can you explain me this?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.contains != 'function') {
    Array.prototype.contains = function (str){
        return this.indexOf(str) > -1;
    };
}

var text = "Hello world";
var tokens = text.split(" ");
console.log(tokens.length);
for (var i in tokens){
    console.log(tokens[i]);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2
"Hello"
"world"
function ()
```

In other words, the "contains" function i added to the Array prototype appears in the for loop as last element (but the array length is 2). Why?

Comment: Because every property created through assignment is *enumerable* and `for/in` iterates over all enumerbale properties.

Answer (score 3):

> Why?

Because [`for-in` doesn't loop through array entries](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html), it loops through *enumerable properties* of an object. You've created a  new enumerable property on `Array.prototype`, and so that property shows up in `for-in` loops on any array.

The solutions are:

1. **Don't do that**, instead loop through arrays [in any of several ways that don't have that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476), or
2. Use `hasOwnProperty` to filter out inherited properties (see link above for more), or
3. Define `contains` as a non-enumerable property via `Object.defineProperty` or similar (you can only do this on ES5+ engines, it cannot be shimmed).